# How to create different output with 4 conditions in excel using COUNTIF and COUNT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula which will display the following;

if =>1 is NOK out of 10, overall is NOK

if out of 10 is, =>1 but <10 is OK, overalll is In Progress

if out of 10 is, 10 is Not Started, overall is Not Started

if out of 10, 10 is OK, overall is OK

I used the following formula;

```
=IF(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"NOK"),"NOK",IF(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")>=1,"In Progress",IF(COUNT(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"Not Started")=10),"Not Started","In Progress")))
```

I can get the first 3 conditions correctly, but the last one, if 10 out of 10 is OK, i still get overall is "In Progress"

Kindly help. Thank you~

Comment: Consider this formulation: `if NOK <= 0 then A else if NOK <= 1 then B else if NOK <= 9 then C else D` (The use of `<=` is consistent to show an incremental pattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
IF(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")>=1,"In Progress",...)
```

`10>=1` is true so it returns `"In Progress"`. Instead, check for 10 first:

```
IF(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")=10,"OK",IF(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")>=1,"In Progress",...))
```

Besides, nowhere in your formula returns `"OK"`.

Comment: Should there not be a <10 condition included giving  the following inside: IF(AND(COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")>=1,COUNTIF(K102:K111,"OK")<10),"In Progress"     as you state in your conditions there must be a less than 10 condition evaluated.

Comment: @QHarr If out of 10 elements, and not all 10 are `"OK"` then definitely `<10` are `"OK"`.